# bxSlider Vertical Slideshow Padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, padding, bxslider

I am using `bxSlider` and am trying to put top padding on my list items.

I can use the `slideMargin` property to add padding to the bottom, but every time I add top padding I get scrollbars.

My current code looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/wswoagbf/

If you go to: http://joshrodg.com/hallmark/ the middle section has an "Events" vertical slider...if you click the `next` arrow you'll see the slider does this weird shuffle and adds a scrollbar.

I'm just looking for a way to add the padding on the top without the weird scrolling\scrollbars - if I take the padding off, everything works fine.

I tried to `prepend` a div with some height on it (using jQuery) and I still get the scrollbars, I think I'm just making this harder than it really is.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I'm just looking for a way to add the padding on the top` - just use padding-top, it works :)

Comment: I have padding on the list-item...I even tried just padding-top and I got the same result.

Comment: `.widget` has padding on both top and bottom, if you remove bottom padding, it works

Comment: Wow...because I did that through a media query I totally forgot about it! My bad!! Thanks for the assist!